# Install Office.js add-in with powershell

Tags: powershell, office-js, office-addins

I have a question if there is any way how to install Office.js Excel add-in from Network share via powershell.
I wasn't able to find any information.

Comment: Is it packaged as an `.xla` file?

Comment: No. It's only xml manifest and the application is running on company server.

Comment: If this blog post doesn't provide what you're looking for, then I think the answer is "no". https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you. It's perfect. I found what I was looking for in that tool source code.